# Python-Asyncio TCP Server keep connecting to another remote TCP server

Tags: python, tcpclient, python-asyncio, asyncsocket, tcpserver

Is there any code snippet sample to achieve the following requirement,

python-asyncio TCP Server listen for TCP client and manage open connection simultaneously to another remote TCP server.

the tcp server code that I've tried so far, based on: http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html[1](http://asyncio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tcp_echo.html)

```
HOST, PORT = '127.0.0.1', 8888
VHOST, VPORT = "localhost", 9999

vsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
vsock.connect((VHOST, VPORT))

async def send_message(message, vsock):
    receive = None
    try:
        vsock.sendall(message)
        received = vsock.recv(1024)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

    return received

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):

    task = loop.create_task(send_message(data, vsock))
    response = await task
    writer.write(response)
    await writer.drain()
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, HOST, PORT, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
vsock.close()
```

It works on first request, but getting blank message in 2nd request, and getting error the next request

```
Unexpected error: <class 'BrokenPipeError'>
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<handle_echo() done, defined at socket_server.py:27> exception=BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hery/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "socket_server.py", line 34, in handle_echo
    response = await task
  File "/home/hery/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 358, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/home/hery/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 290, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "/home/hery/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/home/hery/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "socket_server.py", line 18, in send_message
    vsock.sendall(message)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow the personnasking the question is expected to post a code snippet whers he/she has troubles with. You should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Read more about https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @KlausD. thanks for comment